# matplotlib scatter with c=date

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

How to plot a pandas dataframe like the one below with x on the x-axis, the values on the y-axis (one line per row) and the lines colored by **date**

```
values = [[0.2, 3.1, 17.4, 28.9, 57.7, 76.9, 82.8, 87.6, 92.4, 98.9, 100.0],
          [0.2, 2.1, 15.5, 26.0, 54.2, 75.6, 82.1, 87.4, 92.4, 98.9, 100.0]]

x = [0.1, 0.2, 0.315, 0.4, 0.63, 1, 1.25, 1.6, 2, 3.15, 4]

dates = pd.date_range(start='2017-07-01', freq='D', periods=2)

data = pd.DataFrame(data=values, columns=x)

data['dates'] = dates
```

edit: sorry for not being precise.

Is there a way to set the colors of the lines according to a columns of Timestamps using data[x].T.plot(kind='line', legend=False).

If this is not possible, how to set "c" in plt.scatter to an array of Timestamps?

edit: the plot should look like this but should have a colorbar instead of a legend
[image]

Comment: The question lacks a problem description. What is the desired outcome and what prevents you from obtaining it? The code itself should show the problem as well; is there an error? or do you simply not get the desired plot?

Comment: Still not clear what the desired outcome is. If you leave out the dates column, you can simply do `data.T.plot()` and obtain two lines with different color.

Comment: The original data set has hundreds of rows.I would like to create a plot with a line per row of the dataframe and the color of each line should be defined by the date column. And the relation between color and date should be obvious in colorbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create test data with a structure similar to the real data
x_values = np.linspace(1, 10, 8)
dat = np.random.randn(100, 8)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.abs(dat), columns=x_values)
df = df.cumsum(axis=1)
df = df.divide(df.max(axis=1), axis='index')

# create discontinuos date range and add it to data frame
dates = pd.date_range(start=('2016-01-01'), end=('2017-05-01'), freq='D')
dates = dates[(dates < '2016-07-01') | (dates > '2017-03-01')]
df['date'] = sorted(random.sample(dates.date.tolist(), 100))

# create a dataframe with a continous date range (see df) and corresponding colors
drange = pd.date_range(start=df['date'].min(), end=df['date'].max(), freq='D')
colors = iter(plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, drange.shape[0])))
cdf = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([drange.date, list(colors)]).T, columns=['date', 'colors'])

# and merge colors to data
data = pd.merge(df, cdf)

# plot all data row by row with color of lines
# matching the date columns

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for idx in data.index:
    ax.plot(x_values, data.loc[idx, x_values],
            linestyle='-', alpha=0.75, 
            color=data.loc[idx, 'colors'],
            label=data.loc[idx, 'date'])

# reduce entries of legend
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
entries = int(data.shape[0]/10)
handles = handles[::entries]
labels = labels[::entries]
ax.legend(handles, labels)
```